# Make SSMS new query window contain scripted object name instead of Query1.sql

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Hi I'm working on a database with quite a few nested views. View A will call view B that call C & D etc.

When I want to look at ascript I right-click > script view as > create to > new query editor window.

But now the script is called something SQLQuery27.sql. When you have a lot of views open this is not super helpful to switch back and forth between the views. I've managed to shorten the tab displays already using [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/fixing-sql-server-management-studios-tab-text/) method.

But is there any way for the script name to be the name of the object being scripted? So if I open view named A, the query would be called A.sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with native SSMS means - no. But, in  [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-script-object-from-sql-editor) add-in that I develop you can position the cursor on the view name, hit F2 and it will be scripted in new window, named after your view.

Comment: Perfect! Only the first one is an issue, after that every script generated by that has the correct name.

Comment: Can you please specify what is the remaining issue? (I think I do not understand your reply exactly)

Comment: For the first view, when I script it as create from SSMS, it still gets the Query1.sql naming. What I do now is CTRL-N to create a new sql script. Drag the first view onto it, then press F2 to get correct naming for that first view as well. That is an accpetabel workaround for me.

Comment: Ah you're the author, didn't realise. Kudos! While you're at it, one gripe that still blows my mind about SSMS is importing textfiles. I can't believe that is still such a struggle that leads to multiple failed attempts before it finally works (if at all). I have some ideas on how that could be a click next three times get it right the first time process. Let me know if you want to cooperate.

Comment: Sure: please send me an e-mail to our support@ address and we will see if this can be implemented ;)